# Using addEventListener with object literal

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write my JS using the Good Parts as described by Douglas Crockford and therefore created a single global object `A`. However I am having trouble with my JS code.
The variables `value1` and `value2` are evaluating to `NaN` and I don't understand why.

I have declared the two variables `invoiced` and `lastInvoiced` outside of the `totalInvoiced` and then tried to get them inside the method using `this`. However, I don't know if this is correct? I did this in the hope that I could then use `addEventListener` on those variables and call the `onchange` event.

Why are `value1` and `value2` evalutaing to `NaN`?

How would I write the code to use 'addEventListener' with the onchange event on those two variables?

**[Here is a jsFiddle link to all of my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/MMendes/eKeLt/3/)**

This is my JS code:

```
var A = {

invoiced: document.getElementById("invoiced").value,   
lastInvoiced: document.getElementById("lastinvoiced").value,
totalInvoiced: function () {

 var invoiced1 = this.invoiced;
 var lastInvoiced1 = this.lastInvoiced;
 var value1 = parseFloat("invoiced1");
 var value2 = parseFloat("lastInvoiced1");

     if(isNaN(value1))
         value1 = 0;
     if(isNaN(value2))
         value2 = 0;

 var totalInvoiced1 = value1 + value2;
 var value3 = document.getElementById("daytotal").value = totalInvoiced1 + "€";
 return value3;   
 }

 };
window.onload = A.totalInvoiced();
A.invoiced.addEventListener("change", A.totalInvoiced, false);
A.lastInvoiced.addEventListener("change", A.totalInvoiced, false);
```

Comment: If you have `A = {invoiced: ...value, ...` and `A.invoiced.addEventListener` then you're trying to add an event listener to a _String_?

Comment: Yes remove the `value` property from your Object `A` properties `invoiced` and `lastInvoiced`

Comment: @PaulS., how would I add an event listener to value then? I want the sum `invoiced` + `lastinvoiced` to be calculated when the user inputs and then changes the element value and the result displayed in `totalInvoiced`. I have performed the changes suggested, but it still produces the same result.

Comment: Actually it displays NaN when I run it on JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/MMendes/eKeLt/6/
But when I run it normally in the browser, I have to insert the values and then only when I refresh the page does it execute the sum. Is the problem with the way I've called `addEventListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `parseFloat("invoiced1");` and `parseFloat("lastInvoiced");` are evaluating the **strings** `invoiced1`, `lastInvoiced` - not the variables - change that, so:

```
parseFloat(invoiced1);
parseFloat(lastInvoiced);
```

---

Secondly, the `<input>` elements you are attempting to get the values from don't actually have any values set.

```
  <td><input type="number" id="invoiced" class="boxed" />&euro;</td>
```

Here, `&euro;` is the value of the `<td>`, not the `<input>`. You should give it an initial value - you shouldn't need to test for `NaN` in your code if you write it properly, so remove that check.

---

Thirdly, as mentioned, you're setting the events to the element's value, not the element - try setting them to the elements themselves, and then using `A.invoiced.value;` etc (use `A` instead of `this` as `this` will sometimes refer to different objects in your context, as you are calling it in different ways) instead to grab the value, e.g:

```
invoiced: document.getElementById("invoiced"),
lastInvoiced: document.getElementById("lastinvoiced"),
totalInvoiced: function () {
    var invoiced = A.invoiced.value;
    var lastInvoiced = A.lastInvoiced.value; 
    ...
```

[**Here's an updated jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/eKeLt/8/)

Comment: I have done all the changes you suggested, but I still have the same problem. The program doesn's execute the sum when a user inserts new values into the register. I don't know why but the link I posted to my fiddle had the old version of my HTML. I had given values to my `input` elements, although they were empty values. The link you provided displays the same problem. It does the sum when hardcoded values are set into the `input` element, but will not execute with user input. What could be the problem behind this? Am I not using the `addEventListener` correctly?

Comment: This is my new link. http://jsfiddle.net/MMendes/eKeLt/6/
I hope it has updated properly now.

Comment: Actually it displays NaN when I run it on JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/MMendes/eKeLt/6/
But when I run it normally in the browser, I have to insert the values and then only when I refresh the page does it execute the sum. Is the problem with the way I've called `addEventListener`?

Comment: @MMendes It's to do with your usage of this. Have a look at console.log(this), and  change it to A.invoiced.value; etc and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @MMendes No worries! Sorry, I only tested the window.onload() version  before stupidly without testing the change event haha, glad it works!